# Could not inject Spring service into akka service

Tags: java, spring, jsf, akka, akka-persistence

I have Spring service, which is actually actor, it is received info, but I cant pass it to another Spring service, because injection fails.

```
@Service("mailContainer")
@Scope("prototype")
@Component
public class MailContainer extends UntypedActor {

    private final LoggingAdapter LOG = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);

    private Mail value;
    private List<Mail> mailList = new ArrayList<Mail>();
    private Integer size;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("springService")
    private SpringService springService;

    //@Autowired
    public void setSpringService(SpringService springService) {
        this.springService = springService;
    }

    public MailContainer(Mail value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {

        //    LOG.debug("+ MailContainer message: {} ", message);
        if (message instanceof Mail) {
            value = (Mail) message;
            System.out.println("MailContainer get message with id   " + value.getId());
            System.out.println("With time   " + value.getDateSend());
            //getSender().tell(value, getSelf()); //heta uxarkum
            //this.saveIt(value);
            springService.add(value);
        }

    }
```

and second service

```
@Service("springService")
//@Component
@Scope("session")
public class SpringService {

    private List<Mail> mailList = new ArrayList<Mail>();

    public void add(Mail mail) {
        System.out.println("Saving mail from Spring " +mail.getId());
        mailList.add(mail);

    }

    public List<Mail> getMailList() {

        return mailList;
    }

}
```

Spring config, this is from akka spring example

```
@Configuration
//@EnableScheduling
//EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com"}, excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class)})
//@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-data-context.xml")
//@EnableTransactionManagement
//@EnableMBeanExport
//@EnableWebMvc
public class CommonCoreConfig {


 // the application context is needed to initialize the Akka Spring Extension
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  /**
   * Actor system singleton for this application.
   */
  @Bean
  public ActorSystem actorSystem() {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("AkkaJavaSpring");
    // initialize the application context in the Akka Spring Extension
    SpringExtProvider.get(system).initialize(applicationContext);
    return system;
  }
}
```

So, how I can inject just another Spring service?????????

Comment: how are you creating the MailContainer actor? Please can you show the code where you are executing the actorOf() method. You need to create the MailContainer via the extension to ensure that dependency injection is performed as required.

Comment: I'd expect something like `getContext().actorOf(SpringExtProvider.get(actorSystem).props("mailContainer"))` at the point where you need to create the actor. Spring wont  automatically create the actor for you

Comment: Actors created success with Spring or without Spring, problem is what when I want inject just SPring service, which is not actor based, it was fails, I want for example from last actor pass data to Spring service and save to db. Under tomcat Autowire inject does not working

Comment: The way you create your MailContainer actor is important for dependency injection to work - how do you create an instance of the MailContainer actor? I don't see the code for that in your post. Also what is the exception you get when it fails?

Comment: here is a code from previous actor
  @Override
    public void preStart() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Mail collector preStart: {} ");
         getContext().actorOf(Props.create(MailContainer.class, result), "one");
    }

Comment: and tell  getContext().actorSelection("*").tell(message, getSelf());

Comment: here is a error

Mail collector message: {} Mail{id=96, from=AAA, to=BBBB, content=null, dateSend=Wed Aug 13 13:02:25 AMT 2014}
MailContainer get message with id   96
With time   Wed Aug 13 13:02:25 AMT 2014
[ERROR] [08/13/2014 13:02:26.413] [AkkaJavaSpring-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://AkkaJavaSpring/user/mailCollector/one] null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on our discussions, I think it is due to the way you create the MailContainer actor. You aren't using the SpringExtProvider and instead are using Props.create directly. This means that Spring doesn't get the opportunity to perform dependency injection on your new actor.

Try changing this code:

```
@Override
public void preStart() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Mail collector preStart: {} ");
    getContext().actorOf(Props.create(MailContainer.class, result), "one");
}
```

to use the the SpringExtProvider like this:

```
@Override
public void preStart() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Mail collector preStart: {} ");
    getContext().actorOf(SpringExtProvider.get(getContext().system()).props("mailContainer"), "one");
}
```

This way you are asking the Spring extension to create the new actor and inject any required dependecnies.

Comment: with this changes I see another errors, can you have a look at simple project? here is a link, just run under tomcat, it is maven project https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B45Md1_c5-gGcENISFZxMnI5b2s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what are the errors you are getting? looking at the code for Mailcollector class you have the following line `getContext().actorOf(SpringExtProvider.get(getContext().system()).props(MailContainer.class.getSimpleName()), "one");` - you need to use the name of your Spring bean here e.g. "mailContainer", not MailContainer.class.getSimpleName(). Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Yes, after it I got another error
[ERROR] [08/13/2014 14:31:09.388] [AkkaJavaSpring-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://AkkaJavaSpring/user/mailCollector/one] No Scope registered for scope 'session', and when made spring bean session, no difference, the same error..

Comment: Temporarily can you remove @Scope annotation from the SpringService so it becomes a singleton to see if that works?

Comment: ok.. As I understand if I am using Spring, all actions with actors should be via Spring, because Akka should middleware , I am tring input data to Actors and output it at the end.

Comment: not exactly, there's no stopping you creating an actor that doesn't use Spring's DI, and there may well be cases where is this is appropriate, however when you do need to use Spring DI it must be annotated as a Spring bean and created via the Akka SpringExtension.